# How to convert a gpx track file to csv

Tags: gps

I have been mapping old tracks with Garmin 64s. I want to know how to take a group of way-points that belong to edited/cleaned tracks in my Base-camp and convert them to a format (csv? txt?) that will allow me to share these with another user for upload to his device or computer and into a survey plan, preferably in an excel spreadsheet. Is that the right way to go about it?

I've been told about various software (gpsBabel, GSAK) that are supposed to do this but I do not know the correct process/procedure in applying this software. It is new to me and if you can help please do in real layman's terms, step by step process and correct language formatting, just to get me started.

Comment: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input will do this without the need to download software.

Comment: check this simple tool If you want to do this with code: https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter

Answer (score 2):

Use GPS Babel, it's pretty easy to use.
https://www.gpsbabel.org/download.html
It will allow you to upload to a device as well (see image).

[image: GPS Babel interface]

Answer (score 2):

With python, may I suggest my own [gpxcsv package](https://pypi.org/project/gpxcsv/), which can convert one file or batch convert.

```
gpxcsv *.gpx
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QGIS Desktop or GDAL OGR2OGR like:

```
OGR2OGR -f "CSV" output.csv input.gpx
```